# SQL query matching exact children with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Say I have following tables

```
create table parent (parent_id)

create table child (child_id, parent_id, name)
```

and following rows:

**parent**:

```
(1)
(2)
(3)
```

**child**:

```
(11,1, "1")
(21,2, "1")
(22,2, "2")
(31,3, "1")
(32,3, "2")
(33,3, "3")
```

I need to find parent containing only children named ("1", "2"), i.e. parent_id 2 ,but not parent_id 3.

What is the way to achieve that with simple and fast query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , ok, let it be Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all names into an array and compare that to the list of names you are looking for:

```
select parent_id
from child
group by parent_id
having array_agg(distinct name order by name) = array['1', '2']
```

The `order by name` is important because `['1', '2']` is not equal to `['2', '1']`

Answer (score 2):

You want ***exact relational division***. The following should give you desired result but it assumes that `parent_id, name` pairs are unique:

```
SELECT parent_id
FROM child
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name     IN ('1', '2') THEN 1 END) = 2
AND    COUNT(*) = 2
```

The alternate and somewhat dynamic solution is as follows:

```
WITH input(name) AS (
    SELECT '1' UNION
    SELECT '2'
)
SELECT child.parent_id
FROM child
LEFT JOIN input ON child.name = input.name
GROUP BY child.parent_id
HAVING COUNT(child.name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM input)
AND    COUNT(input.name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM input)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM parent WHERE   parent_id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM children WHERE name LIKE '1') AND parent_id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM children WHERE name LIKE '2')
```

Comment: This query will find parent_id = 3. It should find only exact match of children.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible not to use postgres-specific functions?

Comment: This query would be very big if I'll try to build it for 1000 children names =)

Comment: Sorry @corvax, you were right. I changed my answer.

Comment: How would you identify the 1000 children?

Comment: I mean, are they in a third table?